# What is printed as a result of executing the following code segment? And why does that occur?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

What is printed as a result of executing the code segment that follows?
(I would normally just use the java program on my computer to do this. But, the program is updating, which will take another few hours.) Anyways, here is the code segment:

```
ArrayList<String> digits = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++)
{
digits.add("" + k);
}
for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++)
{
String d1 = digits.remove(k);
String d2 = digits.remove(k);
digits.add(k, d1 + "+" + d2);
}
System.out.println(digits);
```

I also want to know why the answer occurs going through this code by hand. I know I got an answer that was completely wrong, so I would also like to know why the answer that you guys get is the correct answer.

Comment: Seriously? SO is not a compiling service.

Comment: I know. But, I also want to know. Why the answer occurs?

Comment: I went through it without compiling it. And my answer was completely wrong.

Comment: Therefore, I am not merely asking what this compiles to, however I am also asking why that occurs

Comment: You should probably modify the question to reflect this (especially the title) or you will get more downvotes fast.

Comment: Then step through the code in a debugger, examine values as they change.

Comment: @Henry I just modfied the question a little to reflect that I also want why the answer occurs as well. I will change the title too.

Comment: As for @OldProgrammer, I state in the question that the java program/debugger that I am using is updating, so I couldn't just go through it with a debugger.

Comment: @sssemil his answer looks correct below, I just want to know how that answer works.

Comment: The fact that your IDE is updating is completely irrelevant. There are plenty of other ways to compile and test your code, including many online resources. Stack Overflow isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is 
   [0+1, 2+3, 4+5, 6+7, 8+9]

- The numbers ranging from 0 to 9 are added to the array list by the first for-loop.

  ```
  for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) { digits.add("" + k);}
  ```
- Five times 2 numbers are removed, e.g. in the first iteration the numbers 0  and 1 are removed. Keep in mind that remove shifts subsequent elements to the left.
- At the same iteration a string containing the two digits is inserted into the ArrayList at position k.

  ```
  for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++){
    String d1 = digits.remove(k);
    String d2 = digits.remove(k);
    digits.add(k, d1 + "+" + d2);
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you! This explanation is well thought out and very simple/easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Output should be something like this: [0+1, 2+3, 4+5, 6+7, 8+9]. Didn't compile though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to compile your code and run it.

https://www.compilejava.net/

It produces this:
[0+1, 2+3, 4+5, 6+7, 8+9]